# Python: Datetime updating in program, and looping through a list every X seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a simulation (for a hobby project) that runs through the seasons and after each of the four seasons keeps a count of the years passed.

(At a later date will add some plants that reproduce based on seasons and time but can't get past this for now)

I think one of my issues is that I'm not calling sim_time again. The computer stores a value for sim_time and then loops through with just that value.

It is intended to use datetime and the % operator to create a year every 240 seconds. Then every 90 seconds it cycles through a season. When Winter has finished, it loops back to Spring and so on indefinitely. Not sure how to make this happen, or what I'm missing exactly.

Have only been learning Python for a month, happy to take all advice and pointers, any help is sincerely appreciated!

```
import os
from datetime import datetime, time

os.system("cls")


now = datetime.now()
day_start = datetime.combine(now.date(), time(0))
time_now = ((now - day_start).seconds)


spring = "Spring"   # increased harvest
summer = "Summer"   # standard harvest
autumn = "Autumn"   # no harvest
winter = "Winter"   # no harvest


seasons = [spring, summer, autumn, winter]
year = 0


def season(world_time):
    sim_time = int(time_now)
    if sim_time % 360 == 0:
        year += 1
        return year

    if sim_time % 90 == 0:
        # Spring has arrived
        return spring

    elif sim_time % 90 == 0 and sim_time % 180 == 0:
        # Summer has arrived
        return summer

    elif sim_time % 90 == 0 and sim_time % 180 == 0 and sim_time % 270 == 0:
        # Autumn has arrived
        return autumn

    else:
        # Winter has arrived
        return winter


while True:
    season(time_now)
    print(season(time_now))
    print(year)

# end of file
```

Comment: `year` isn't tracked

Comment: @roganjosh actually, i think it is on L19. Yeah @user8086054 the problem could be fixed by putting your ```"now = datetime.now()"``` ```"time_now = ((now - day_start).seconds)"``` at the start of the while loop

Comment: @groteworld will give it a go now, and edit this comment with the result thanks!

Edit: Haven't noticed a difference as it's providing the same result as before.

Comment: nvm @roganjosh was right, your are trying to access a global variable year. We don't need to get into globals now, but just know you can't reference a variable outside of a function unless you define it as global. (seriously it's a bad habit to get into)

Comment: Alright thanks @roganjosh (love a rogan josh btw) and @groteworld. So inside the function I should write `global year` ?

Edit: Thanks this definitely made a change - now it did update the year, except it showed 12476. 

`Winter
12476
`

Comment: still trying to solve this :(

Answer (score 0):

Remove year calculation for now, as you can't access that variable outside of a function.

The problem is around `day_start = datetime.combine(now.date(), time(0))`

I would just make that a `datetime.now()` as it will track when it is started.

Comment: not sure how to make this work! I get errors this way.